# Compare similar images and point out the differences in second image using python

Tags: python

I need to compare 2 similar images (with little differences) and need to highlight the differences (x,y coordinates) in the second image.

Please suggest me the efficient way to do it using Python?

I am working on a project to show 2 similar images and the user need to identify the differences. If the user correctly click the difference area in the second image, I need to count and show the user on how much he identified?

Comment: Hi Jerish, this is not the right format for a question on SO, please provide an example code block that you're having trouble with, and the community can help you make it better.

Comment: Hi, I am new to python and need your help to start with the correct logic.

Comment: If you're new to Python, you'll need to learn a bit more before tackling this problem. Don't expect people on StackOverflow to solve your specific problem if you haven't tried solving it yourself. However, I can suggest this: read in both images as numpy arrays, subtract them and then anywhere the difference is not zero is where the images are different. If you understand the previous phrase, you can solve it yourself. Look into [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/).

Comment: Oliver, thanks for your great help. Let me try with Numpy array.